# Elixir: How to send notification to server in handle_cast?

Tags: elixir, actor, gen-server

I am making basic Elixir server/client module that can send/receive asynchronous messages. The module looks like following.

```
defmodule Bitcoin.WorkerOne do
use GenServer

def start_link(opts) do
    IO.puts " - Worker 1 started - "
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,:ok, opts)
end

def set_message(server, name, mid) do
    GenServer.cast(server, {:set_message, name})
end

#callbacks
def init(:ok) do
    names = []
    {:ok, names}
end

def handle_cast({:set_message, name},names) do
    IO.puts "- new state is - " 
    names = names ++name
    IO.inspect names
    {:noreply,names}
end

end
```

I am initiating the processes through iex console using.

```
{:ok, pid1} = Bitcoin.WorkerOne.start_link([])
Bitcoin.WorkerOne.get_message(pid1, ["one"])
```

After the above , the state gets change to ['one'] (initially empty list). I want to send a notification back to the server that the state has been updated. Can I call `'Genserver.cast'` inside the `handle_cast`, in order to send a message back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the sender's pid in the message to the server when using casts where you want to send a notification, but it's better to use calls combined with `GenServer.reply/2`, returning `{:noreply, state}` in the `handle_call` callback for that use case, to get the guarantee that the server received the request. Manually reimplementing replies is a lot of work depending on what guarantees you need, so you should avoid it.

Comment: In case of handle_call, it will wait for the task to complete. Does`{:noreply, state}` works around that?

Comment: Using calls from the client is important when you either need a reply, or a guarantee that the server received the request and is acting on it. If you return `{:noreply, state}`, it is expected that you have either already replied or will reply in the future using `GenServer.reply/2`. This allows you to control when replies are sent while maintaining the guarantees provided by calls, including handling timeouts and crashes. The caller will block, but you can reply early to minimize that, or use casts along with the caster's pid if the request is truly fire and forget.